# What would cause a Drupal site to display a 500 error or a blank page depending on browsers?

Tags: 7, wsod

After moving a site to the final server, I cannot anymore access the site. When I go to the home page, I get a WSD on Firefox, and a 500 error on Google Chrome.

As it is a shared hosting, I cannot access the Apache error log, and I am wondering if anyone experienced that before. How did you find your way out of it?

Comment: If you actually can't view your own error logs you need to get a new host.

Comment: You either failed to copy the .htaccess file or there could be a file like default.html in the root directory taking more precedence over index.php

Comment: Yeah good advice, but are you sure i would get a 500 error in that case ? Though i checked and i just have index.php in that particular directory. Thanks for your input

Comment: Could it be something with different timeouts on different browsers?

Comment: I have found the reason for HTTP 500 error inside my cpanel logs: Fri Dec 29 13:29:09.349754 2017] [:error] [pid 284970] [client 83.184.116.216:56443] SoftException in Application.cpp:261: File "/home/sprint/public_html/install.php" is writeable by group [Fri Dec 29 13:28:43.972883 2017] [:error] [pid 284475] [client 83.184.116.216:56441] SoftException in Application.cpp:261: File "/home/sprint/public_html/index.php" is writeable by group Desired permissions for these 2 files are 644. However, for some reason my uploaded files ended up with 664 permission and therefore HTTP 500 error appeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article about [The White Screen of Death (Completely Blank Page)](http://drupal.org/node/158043) is a good place to start.

Depending on your shared host, you can often get access to logs if you poke around your control panel, or they sometimes are copied into your home directory.

Since you explicitly mentioned shared hosting, your best best is to open a trouble ticket.  They can tell you exactly what is wrong fairly easily.

If it is a true 500 error, then my guess is that one of these two lines in the .htaccess is causing the problem.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

You can try commenting them out one at a time and see what happens.  I suspect that your host has `AllowOverride` set to `None` and one of those is trying to set a non-default value that the host has set.

Comment: Thank you MPD, suggestion much appreciated. I can not test them right now but i should be able to very soon. I ll make sure to let every one knows how that turns out.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your main question, nothing is making the server behave differently based on your browser - it's just the browsers displaying the results of a 500 error differently.

But, as for a solution to the underlying 500 error - other things to check;

PHP version - is the final server running a different version?

[PHP memory limit](http://drupal.org/node/29268)

Comment: Thanks for the hint Garry, as i mentioned above i have to hold on for this issue but i ll make sure to keep this question update when the time comes